# How to add image url in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have some code of c# and i want to add some images in c# code via url but it is not happen to add so please tell me what is wrong in this code.
My project name is ProjectDemo and i have folder images that have maintain all images.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        collection = new ObservableCollection<Image> { 
            new Image{ Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
            new Image{Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway-1.png", UriKind.Relative))}, 
            new Image{ Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo/images/part-5.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
            new Image{Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/part-6.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
             new Image{ Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/part-7.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
            new Image{Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/part-8.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
             new Image{ Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/speed-1.png", UriKind.Relative))} ,
            new Image{Height=128, Width=128,Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/speedroad.png", UriKind.Relative))} 
         };
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[0]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[1]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[2]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[3]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[4]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[5]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[6]);
         FirstListBox.Items.Add(collection[7]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a friendly advice, learn MVVM before writing single line of code in wpf.

First make sure that you have Images included in the project and their `BuildAction` is `"Resource"`

Then in your VM or code behind you can do

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeImages();
            DataContext = this;

        }

        private void InitializeImages()
        {
            ImageModels.Add(new ImageModel
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway.png", UriKind.Relative))
            });
            ImageModels.Add(new ImageModel
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway-1.png", UriKind.Relative))
            });
            ImageModels.Add(new ImageModel
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/part-5.png", UriKind.Relative))
            });
        }


        ObservableCollection<ImageModel> _imageModels = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();

        ObservableCollection<ImageModel> ImageModels
        {
            get { return _imageModels; }
        }
    }

    public class ImageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ImageSource imageSource;

        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return imageSource; }
            set
            {
                imageSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

and in your `View`

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImageModels}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Height="128" Width="128" Source="{Binding Source}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to write absolute [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g. `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway.png")` instead of `new Uri("/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway.png", UriKind.Relative)`.

Comment: @Clemens I second that

Comment: Moreover there is no strict need for having BitmapImages in the view model. You could as well have URI strings, as WPF provides built-in automatic conversion from `string` (and `Uri`) to `ImageSource`.

Comment: @Clemens I think that only holds true when we set string directly in xaml. If we bind it to string property it does not convert it to Imagesource

Comment: That's not true. WPF automatically converts strings or Uris to ImageSource, regardless if you write it directly in XAML or if you have a binding to a property. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/ProjectDemo;component/images/highway.png"));
```